# How to display error when using is_active for Login

Tags: django

I set a user.is_active to false so they can't login.

```py
user.is_active = False
user.save()
```

I would like to override the login section to show that the account has been disabled. Currently it shows on disabled accounts.

```
Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.
```

I am using the auth login:

```py
path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

With a simple template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

  <h2>Log In</h2>
  <form method="POST" action="."enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Log In</button>
    <button><a href="{% url 'signup' %}">Sign up</a></button>
  </form>
  
{% endblock %}
```

I have seen something like where they override clean and call this function.

```py
def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
    if not user.is_active:
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            "This account has been disabled",
            code='inactive',
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                auth_login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                messages.error(request,'User blocked')
                return redirect('login')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'username or password not correct')
            return redirect('login')

    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/login.html',{'form':form})
```

Just had to check is_active then send messages.error  after overriding login.